# If $x>y+1$, then $xy<(x-1)(y+1)$ ??

Tags: inequality

I'm reading a paper on theoretical CS and there's a something really confuses me. it said:

> If $(x,y)$ are two positive integers and $x>y+1$, we must have $xy<(y+1)(x-1)$.

Well, I can't say I'm buying this, to me, I think because we have $x>y+1$, and $x,y$ are positive, we should have $xy>(y+1)y$ and $x-1>y$.

Thus, for the inequality $xy<(y+1)(x-1)$, we have on the right hand side a factor larger than $y$ and a factor less than $x$, for me it seems nothing can be said for the comparison of $xy$ and $(y+1)(x-1)$. To me it is not conclusive. but the paper wrote it as a lemma without a proof, the author seems to see this inequality as trivial so I think this inequality should stand. But I don't have a clue why this is right. Please help me with this, tell me what did I miss, thank you very much!

Comment: The right hand is $xy+x-y-1$, but we know $x-y-1>0$.

Comment: Hint x<y iff 0<y-x (in fact it's the definition ) use this and see . Lulu comment is a answer

Answer (score 2):

Write:  $$x>y+1\implies x-y-1>0\implies xy+x-y-1>xy\implies (y+1)(x-1)>xy$$ as desired.

You do not need $x,y$ to be positive integers here.